# javascript(jquery ajax) in php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file in which I have written javscript code.
Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("Start");
$.ajax({
     type:...
     url:...
     success:function(data, textStatus ){
       alert("Success");
       Jquery Cycle plugin
     }
     error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert("Failure");
     }
  });
});
```

I have a javascript code in php file with extension .php.When I run the above code,php gets executed perfectly.But javascript code is not executing.This I am saying because even the alert() in the first line of script is not getting executed.I am not getting any ajax error or success function printed which is defined in ajax call.

Comment: What happens if you put your jQuery in the `<body>` rather than in the head. I usually work in the body and PHP + Javascript combinations work perfectly fine, but I haven't tried in the head so dont know if it would work

Comment: Also, do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: what console I am writing code in notepad++ and testing it in browser

Comment: do you you close the script tag?

Comment: The browser console, do you get any errors?

Comment: I put javascript code in the body part but still it is not working

Comment: Do you have any browser console errors?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed commas (,) in the ajax function.

It’s working at my end with the following changes:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("Start");
$.ajax({
 type:'GET',
 url:'somepage.php',
 success:function(data, textStatus ){
   alert("Success");

 },
 error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
   alert("Failure");
 }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("Start");
$.ajax({
     type:'GET',
     url:'somepage.php',
     success:function(data, textStatus ){
       alert("Success");

     },
     error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
       alert("Failure");
     }
  })
});
</script>
```

[Also running on JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3swwvwt4/).